# How to fix a Mad Lib in python?

Tags: python

I have tried so many things to fix. This suppose to be easy but I can't get it to work. I'm also using Repl.it as my IDE.
it stop working after I put my last variable in. Please help

```
    hobby = input("Please put your favorite thing to do: ")
person = input("Please put a person: ")
job = input("Please put a job: ")

print("I love to", + hobby)
print("I am", + person)
print("I want to be", + job)
```

Comment: In the print statement use either `,` or `+` not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, you can use a `+` with a space at the end of the prefixing string, or use a comma without the space:

```
hobby = input("Please put your favorite thing to do: ")
person = input("Please put a person: ")
job = input("Please put a job: ")

print("I love to " + hobby)
print("I am " + person)
print("I want to be " + job)
```

OR

```
hobby = input("Please put your favorite thing to do: ")
person = input("Please put a person: ")
job = input("Please put a job: ")

print("I love to", hobby)
print("I am", person)
print("I want to be", job)
```